# redirecting with javascript if a radiobox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, radio-button, forms

I'm having some issues with a js script that I made (probably because is not the right way but i came up with this idea).
Basically I have a form with some radio buttons in it. Yes or No

```
<form action="#" method="POST" OnSubmit="return check()">
<input type="radio" id="effettuato" name="sicep" value="Effettuato" />Effettuato <br/>
<input type="radio" id="noneffettuato" name="sicep" value="Non Effettuato" />Non Effettuato <br/>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invia" button style="height:50px;width:150px">
</form>
```

Now I made this JavaScript script because I'd like to stop the user if none radio button is selected.

```
    function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('effettuato').checked) {
        window.location = 'processiorari.php';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('noneffettuato').checked) {
        window.location = 'processiorari.php';
    }
    else {
        alert('Seleziona tutti i campi per continuare!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

If he has selected an option I'd like to redirect him to another page called

> processorari.php

The page where those line are written is

> orari.php

Any help? I'm just doing the redirect wrong or the entire concept is wrong?
All the files are in the same folder and I'm running everything using xampp

Comment: put `console.log("here");` inside of your `check()` function. Run your script, select the radio button and check the console for the output. Hint: it wont print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use required="required" in the fields and set the form action to the page you want to redirect.

```html
<form action="processorari.php" method="POST">
  <input type="radio" id="effettuato" name="sicep" value="Effettuato" required="required" />Effettuato <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="noneffettuato" name="sicep" value="Non Effettuato" required="required" />Non Effettuato <br/>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invia" button style="height:50px;width:150px">
</form>
```

Comment: It was very easy.. Now I feel dumb. That fixed it thanks! Since I have multiple questions that is the best way. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [click event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) to achieve this. When the button is clicked, it checks if the radio button is checked, if it is then it'll redirect using `window.location.href`. There is no need to use the submit.

```js
document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(document.getElementById('effettuato').checked) {
    window.location.href = 'processiorari.php';
  } else if(document.getElementById('noneffettuato').checked) {
    window.location.href = 'processiorari.php';
  } else {
    alert('Seleziona tutti i campi per continuare!');
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="radio" id="effettuato" name="sicep" value="Effettuato" />Effettuato <br/>
<input type="radio" id="noneffettuato" name="sicep" value="Non Effettuato" />Non Effettuato <br/>
<input class="button" id="submit-btn" type="button" name="submit" value="Invia" button style="height:50px;width:150px">
</form>
```

Comment: Even tho I copied your code is not redirecting for me, the page turn from
orari.php into orari.php? and that's it

Comment: perhaps there is an issue somewhere else then, does that file exist? is that file in the correct location? @TheNoobUser

Comment: I already fixed my issue but regarding your code yeah I realized i added 1 extra letter to the redirect file name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue if this is the right way to do it but somehow this work just fine

```
    function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('effettuato').checked) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('noneffettuato').checked) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Non puoi lasciare un campo in bianco!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

and i leave in my form the action just like this

```
<form action="processorari.php" method="POST" OnSubmit="return check()">
<input type="radio" id="effettuato" name="sicep" value="Effettuato" />Effettuato <br/>
<input type="radio" id="noneffettuato" name="sicep" value="Non Effettuato" />Non Effettuato <br/>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invia" button style="height:50px;width:150px">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check which check box is checked and redirect page accordingly:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#mychckbx1').prop('checked') ?  window.location.href = 'page1.php' : false;

     $('#mychckbx2').prop('checked') ?  window.location.href = 'page2.php' : false;

  });
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are calling the `check()` function only when the form is submitted. Other than that I can't see anything wrong.

It will work if you change `onsubmit` to `onchange` like this:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" onchange="check()">
    <input type="radio" id="effettuato" name="sicep" value="Effettuato"  />Effettuato <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="noneffettuato" name="sicep" value="Non Effettuato" />Non Effettuato <br/>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invia" button style="height:50px;width:150px">
</form>
```

Comment: The main problem is `window.location` should be `window.location.href`, `onchange` will not fix OP's problem, the button is designed to activate the method.

Comment: yeah but with onchange it will redirect me as soon as I click the radio button. I want it to rederect when I click the send button

Comment: My bad, you didn't say in OP you wanted it to redirect when you click the send button.

Comment: @Jaquarh `window.location` or `window.location.href` wouldn't make a difference

Comment: @Kyle No sorry I didn't specified it in my question so it's my bad